# How to replace NaNs by average of preceding and succeeding values in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have some missing values and I would like to replace all NaN with average of preceding and succeeding values, how can I do that ?.

I know I can use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` with `method='ffill'` or `method='bfill'` options to replace the NaN values by preceding or succeeding values, however I would like to apply the average of those values on the dataframe instead of  iterating over rows and columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`DataFrame.interpolate()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#interpolation).  Example from the panda docs:

```
In [65]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
   ....:                    'B': [.25, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 12.2, 14.4]})
   ....: 

In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
     A      B
0  1.0   0.25
1  2.1    NaN
2  NaN    NaN
3  4.7   4.00
4  5.6  12.20
5  6.8  14.40

In [67]: df.interpolate()
Out[67]: 
     A      B
0  1.0   0.25
1  2.1   1.50
2  3.4   2.75
3  4.7   4.00
4  5.6  12.20
5  6.8  14.40
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering to know how two consecutive NaN are calculated. I found the formulas of linear interpolation online for points (e.g. (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)). In the description of DataFrame.interplate(), it is applied column by column by default. but no more details about how this case can be calculated

Comment: For the default interpolation method, 'linear', the index is ignored.  The delta for each consecutive NaN is calculated as the difference between the know values divided by the number of steps.  In column B in the example above, the difference in known values is 4.00 - 0.25 = 3.75. The number of steps is the number of NaNs in a row + 1 = 2+1 = 3. The delta is 3.75 / 3 = 1.25.  So the first Nan is 0.25 + 1.25 = 1.50 and the second NaN is 1.50 + 1.25 = 2.75.

Comment: The `limit` option is worth mentioning, it allows to prevent filling two many consecutive NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but I just had the same question and the (unique) answer in this page did not satisfy my expectations. That's why I am answering now.
Your post states that you want to replace the `NaNs` with **averages** however, the interpolation is not a correct answer for me because it fills the empty cells with a linear equation. If you want to fill it with the **averages of the preceding and succeeding** rows. This code helped me:

```py
dfb = df.fillna(method='bfill')
dff = df.fillna(method='ffill')
dfmeans = (dfb+dff)/2
dfmeans
```

For the datafrme of the example above, the result looks like

```
    A   B
0   1.0 0.250
1   2.1 2.125
2   3.4 2.125
3   4.7 4.000
4   5.6 12.200
5   6.8 14.400
```

Where you can see, at index 2 of the column A they both produce 3.4 because there the interpolation is (2.1 + 4.7)/2 but in column B the values differ.

For a one-line script and it's application to time series, you can see this post: [Average between values with unevenly distributed time in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018718/average-between-values-with-unevenly-distributed-time-in-pandas-dataframe)